# Linear Algebra Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

here is a picture of the problems.

http://tinypic.com/r/5f26ug/8

Can you help me get started on the problem?

I don't understand how to solve the problem when given matrices in the basis. Also how is the change of coordinate matrix a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: i have no idea...I have no idea what to do because c is made of 2x2 matrices. I can do problems if for example C is made  of columns

Comment: just a random question. If i have the change of matrix from b->c and c-> d. How can I get the change of matrix from b-> D. Can I multiply them together?

Comment: Let $id: V\rightarrow V$ be the identity map, so if we choose a basis $B,C,D$  for $V$, so we can form $[id]_B^D= [id]_C^D [id]_B^C$ which correspond to matrix multiplication.

Comment: so back to the original question, the inverse if C-> B but I don't see how that helps me solve the question

Comment: @user123204 You can identify the space of $2\times 2$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}^4$. Just write the matrix as a column vector.

Comment: ok you have $[id]_B^C$ so the changes of bases from $B$ to $C$ and you know $C$, so let $B_1$, clearly $[B_1]_B=e1$, i.e, $(1,0,0,0)^T$ because is a bases and $B_1= 1*B_1 +0 *B_2+0*B_3+0*B4$ so $[B_1]_C= [id]_B^C[B_1]_B=[id]_B^C *e_1$ so $[B_1]_C$ is equal to your first column express in $C$, i.e., $B_1= -C_1+C_4$ and so on.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks alot @JoseAntonio

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry the inverse was a mistake I read very quickly. In gral. $B_j$ whatever is, is expresses in the order basis as $[B_j]_B= ej$  for $j=1,2,3,4$ and so you know how to calculate  $[B_j]_c$, i.e., $B_j$ expresses in C which is nothing more than a product $[B_j]_c= [id]_B^C [B_j]_B = [id]_B^C ej=([id]_B^C)^j $ the j-th column of your matrix, i.e., $B_j = \sum_i A_{ij} C_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the matrix represent the change of $B$ to $C$, i.e. $[id]_B^C$. Now you want to know $B=\{B_j\}$ for $j=1,2,3,4$. Well what is $B_j$ in $B$, i.e., $[B_j]_B$. Since $B$ is a basis the expression is unique, so $B_j= 1*B_j$ and zero otherwise, i.e., $[B_j]_B= e_j$. Now you know how to changes from $B$ into $C$ by the matrix $[id]_B^C$, so $[B_j]_C=[id]_B^C[B_1]_B=[id]_B^C\cdot e_j=([id]_B^C)^j$, i.e, the $j$-th column of your matrix. Thus $B_j = \sum_{i=1}^4 A_{ij}\cdot C_i$, where $A_{i,j}=([id]_B^C)_{i,j}$.

In particular we have $B_1= -C_1+C_4$ and similarly for the other $B_j$.